# Get data from read-only Google Sheets with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am mirroring a Google Sheets data into a local MySQL database. I am pulling the sheet data in JSON format, parse to extract the information I need and insert that into the DB.

I do not have control over the data that gets added to the sheets, and it is possible that rows may be added or deleted in between existing data, or added at the end. So my question here is: how can I compare what's on the sheet versus what's already in the DB so I don't end up with either duplicate or missing data.

Currently I am parsing the JSON data into an array of just the pieces that I need:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(9) "2016-10-8"
    ["location"]=>
    string(15) "Berlin, Germany"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2016-10-22"
    ["location"]=>
    string(13) "Nashville, TN"
  }
}
```

I then inject this into the MySQL DB.

At a later time, I want to come back, fetch the remote data again, and compare it with what's already in the DB and remove what's no longer in the dataset, and add any new data that's been added. And it's this part that I'm struggling with. I can query the DB and build the same array format to compare, however since it's a multidimensional array, I can't use array_diff().

So how best should I approach this? I don't think looping through the dataset and checking each individual row is the most efficient way to do it, but I suppose that's one option.

Comment: What's the question here? How to diff multidimentional arrays in PHP? Or you need more help with parsing those sheets? Or what?

Comment: Separate question. Why do you want to "keep" or "delete" some records? Are there any triggers on that table, so "keep" or "delete" have extra side effects? Those rows will be referenced from other tables, and you don't wont to break references?

Comment: Yes, the tables are referenced elsewhere and the data needs to be current with what's on the sheet. As for what the actual question is, it's more of a 'how do I approach this'. Is doing a multi dimension array comparison the best way to do this, or is there a better or easier way. I did also just realize that from the sheet, there are only a small set of those rows that are 'active' at any given time, so technically I wouldn't have to compare the entire dataset everytime. But I'm still looking at how to make sure my MySQL DB is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

If: Don't do this! is not an acceptable answer...

Your code will have to be configurable, flexible, and clean so that maintenance is easy. If you can avoid Cartesian join between those two data sets, maybe there is some subset of data that can be used as a key or composite key?

You can put all the data from spreedsheet into hashmaps in PHP, and then "join" is quite fast.

If not, manual comparision of each row may be next best thing.

Last advice. Make sure that calls to DB are batched. Too long a query will bring down DB parsers. (e.g. if you DELETE .... WHERE ....id IN (10 000 ids))